# Disabling Enter to Submit text on Facebook Messenger web version using Javascript in Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, submit, newline, tampermonkey, messenger

To help a family member not send text too early on FB Messenger Web, I'm trying to write some JS to interpret Enter as Shift+Enter so to make a newline/break instead of submitting/sending the text. So far I have the following, but I'm not sure it's the right way to approach this, and it also sends multiple newlines so the result when pressing enter has a newline, the text, and another newline. Can you guide me in the right direction? Nowhere on the web can I find anything similar of changing Enter submissions of text in textareas to newline or breaks instead. Only in the SocialFixer FB extension where new comments are not submitted by pressing enter, but only by Ctrl+Enter or a new button created for the purpose.

Code:

```
['keydown'].forEach((eventName) => {
  window.addEventListener(
    eventName,(e) => {e.stopPropagation();},
    true // capturing input
  );
});
```

Something like this doesn't work as well, probably because of the architecture of the underlying system?

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.keyIdentifier=='U+000A'||e.keyIdentifier=='Enter'||e.keyCode==13 || e.which === 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagate();
            return false;
        }
},true);

document.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
    if(e.keyIdentifier=='U+000A'||e.keyIdentifier=='Enter'||e.keyCode==13 || e.which === 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagate();
            return false;
        }
},true);
```

Generally, the consistency across the web is annoying, some web apps make newlines or breaks on pressing Enter, whereas others submit input. For elderly, I'm trying to standardize this - one thing at a time ;)

Best,

Emb

Comment: Could you show the whole code?

Comment: I'm afraid that's what I have, @cuzi

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see on the Messenger page is that it does not use a textarea, it uses [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)

The following works for me to prevent enter. However I don't know if there is a easy solution to add a newline as the Messenger seems to capture the shift+enter and inserts a newline by adding several new  elements

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         fb messenger prevent enter
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.messenger.com/t/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function preventEnter () {
  // Find the input fields, messenger uses a contenteditable not a textarea
  document.querySelectorAll('*[contenteditable]').forEach(function (editableNode) {
    if ('processed' in editableNode.dataset) {
      // we already attached the event listener
      return
    }
    editableNode.dataset.processed = true
    // Attach event Listener
    editableNode.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      if (!e.shiftKey && (e.key === 'Enter' || e.code === 'Enter')) {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
      }
    })
  })
}

// Run every second again, because the messenger page changes without reloading the page
window.setInterval(preventEnter, 1000)
```